# WebView not loading URL - Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, rss

Recently I made an RSS reader, and my table view shows a bunch of NEW news displayed from a website RSS feed. When you click on the cell it takes you to a new view controller and it shows the full article in it.

There is 2 classes in this project:

- The AMain class gets the RSS feed, and is the tableview delegate/datasource.
- The ADetail class displays the website in the Webview.

Here's the code so you can analyse it.

**AMain.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AMain : UITableViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate> {

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

**AMain.m**

```
#import "AMain.h"
#import "ADetail.h"

@interface AMain () {

    NSXMLParser *parser;
    NSMutableArray *feeds;
    NSMutableDictionary *item;
    NSMutableString *title;
    NSMutableString *link;
    NSString *element;

}
@end

NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

@implementation AMain
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://bountyboulevardss.eq.edu.au/?cat=3&feed=rss2"];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];

}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return feeds.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];
    return cell;
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    element = elementName;

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        title   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        link    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    }

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [title appendString:string];
    } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [link appendString:string];
    }

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];

        [feeds addObject:[item copy]];

    }

}
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"link"];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:string];

    }
}
@end
```

In the end is the prepareForSegue.
Now here is the detail files which is the files that manage the web view:

**aADetail.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ADetail : UIViewController
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *url;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@end
```

**ADetail.m**

```
#import "ADetail.h"

@interface ADetail ()

@end

@implementation ADetail

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString: [self.url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                                          NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@end
```

Here is quick summary of error:
I have a static table which is a RSS feed, it gets the news and displays it when I click on the cell it will take me to a view controller with a `UIWebView` and it is *meant* to show the link of which the news is on, but the webview displays no content.

Comment: Just copy/pasted your code into a new Master-Detail project, and it worked like a charm. Are you sure you set the segue name in your Storyboard? Try placing a breakpoint in `-prepareForSegue:` and check that all values are as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked for me like a charm. :D Now I can continue with my project. Also I had to make sure the Segue identifier was the same as what I declared.