# Removing website content using HTML (Xcode)

Tags: html, objective-c, xcode, wordpress, webview

This is a very hard question, for all of you. Maybe some of you can answer it and if you do you are a life saver. Ok so my project is an RSS Feed which displays the news and when you click on it, it takes you to the page of the article. The website I am getting this feed from has menu and the user HAS to scroll down each time to view the full article. :(

So I know in WebView you can embed code into the web view, I was wondering if there was some code in HTML of how you can actually delete this menu. I add some screen shots. Look :

[image]

It is a Wordpress website, if you could give me the HTML code it would be awesome but it would be even better if you can give me the Xcode code to do this as well.

Thanks to everyone that takes the time to read / reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use css to hide the menu:

```
#nav_menu-2 {
    display: none;
}
```

In your context, you can automatically apply this change by injecting a Javascript script in your webview, which will apply the css rule to your element:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *js = @"document.getElementById('nav_menu-2').style.display = 'none';";
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
}
```

However, this is far from perfect as the js snippet will be executed after the page has finished loading, so the user will see the menu disappear.

EDIT:

If you don't want to reference the `div`'s id, you could use the class `widget_nav_menu`:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *js = @"var menus = document.getElementsByClassName('widget_nav_menu');"
        "for (var i = 0; i < menus.length; i++) {"
        "menus[i].style.display = 'none';"
        "}";
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
}
```

Beware that this will hide **all** elements with this class (but this could be what you need).

Comment: Thanks I am alright with the user seeing it disappear I will try your and Mikode's method and tick the one that works best!

Comment: Do i need to know the menu ID is there a way to do it without it, cause it aint my website :). Sorry . Im beginner to WEB type of stuff.

Comment: Pretty much. You'll always need a way to reference the menu in the DOM. I updated my answer to use the class of the div instead of its id, this may be more future-proof.

Comment: Sorry the only reason I don't understand this stuff is cause I am 13 and I am making an app for my school. I just started last month. "O" Well thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Can you supply a link or the html for the menu?

A frontend solution would be to use javascript/jQuery with something like:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#your-menu-id').hide();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry one problem with that , I don't own the website, So i don't know the ID.

Comment: If you provided a link then you can find the ID in the source pr with inspect element but as the CSS answer by @GuillaumeAlgis would probably be better.

Comment: @Mikode :) I kinda cheated on this one. I answered [a question from Xcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709197/webview-not-loading-url-xcode) yesterday, and recognized the website. The URL is http://bountyboulevardss.eq.edu.au/?p=15313.

Comment: thx for helping guys. Appreciate it. BTW why do you think I am making a app for a school. Im 13 :)